# Выдает -1.#IND00

Tags: c

Делаю реализацию метода Гаусса для решения систем линейных уравнений. На выходе получаю -1.#IND00. В чем ошибка?

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

void gauss(double **as, double *bs, int number){
    int i, j, k, c = 0, w;
    double *x = (double*)malloc(number*sizeof(double));
    double up;

    for(i = 1; i<number; ++i){
        double *m = (double*)malloc((number-i)*sizeof(double));

        for(j = 0; j<number-i; ++j){
            m[j] = as[j+1][c]/as[c][c];
        }

        for(k = 1; k<number; ++k){
            for(j = 0; j<number; ++j){
                as[k][j] = as[k][j] - as[c][j]*m[k-1];
            }
            bs[k] = bs[k] - bs[c]*m[k-1];
        }

        ++c;

        free(m);
    }

    x[number-1] = bs[number-1]/as[number-1][number-1];

    for(i = number-2; i>=0; --i){
        up = bs[i];
        for(j = number-1; j>i; --j){
            up = up - as[i][j]*x[j];
        }
        x[i] = up/as[i][i];
        up = 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i<number; ++i){
        printf("X%d = %lf\n", i+1, x[i]);
    }

    free(x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int number, i, j;

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("equationsystem.txt", "r");

    if(f == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(f, "%d", &number);

    double **as;
    as = (double**)malloc(number*sizeof(double*));

    for(i = 0; i<number; ++i){
        as[i] = (double*)malloc(number*sizeof(double));
    }

    double *bs = (double*)malloc(number*sizeof(double));

    for(i = 0; i<number; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j<number; ++j){
            fscanf(f, "%lf", &as[i][j]);
        }
        fscanf(f, "%lf", &bs[i]);
    }

    fclose(f);

    gauss(as, bs, number);

    for(i = 0; i<number; ++i){
        free(as[i]);
    }

    free(as);
    free(bs);

    return 0;
}
```

Текст файла:

```
5
16 2 3 2 2 21
2 56 2 2 1 117
1 3 24 1 2 -16
3 2 3 24 1 75
2 1 3 1 56 -52
```

Comment: Детально не смотрел, но подозреваю стандартную ошибку: в результате преобразований матрицы ее диагональные элементы могут стать равными 0. У вас в коде не видно никакой защиты от этого. Деление `as[j+1][c]/as[c][c]` может оказаться делением на 0 со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: Формально - не ошибка, но очень странная идея в "быстром" цикле (у Вас же мало элементов в массиве/матрице) на каждой итерации выделять и освобождать память: `double *m = (double*)malloc((number-i)*sizeof(double));`. Выделите перед циклом себе памяти на `number` элементов и просто не используйте "лишние" элементы. Цикл будет работать гораздо быстрее как минимум. А освободите в конце функции.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код занимается какой-то ерундой. На итерации `i` выделяется и заполняется массив `m` размера `number - i`, то есть на каждой итерации главного цикла массив `m` становится все меньше и меньше. Однако цикл по `k` всегда, на каждой итерации главного цикла, смело доступается до элементов `m` с индексами от `0` до `number - 1`, совершенно игнорируя фактический размер массива `m`.

Дальше можно не смотреть. Пока что это выглядит как весьма неортодоксальная реализация метода Гаусса.